# Adding element on hover w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add a box to  the end of the div when I hover on that div. The div needs to stay when I roll ontoit from .myDiv and must go away if I click within it or anywhere outside, but not if I click within .myDiv. Also if i hover out from .myDiv the yellow div needs to close.

```
var yHeight = $(".yDiv").height();

$(".myDiv").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).append($("<div class="yDiv"> ... </div>"));
      }, 
      function () {
        $(this).find(".yDiv").remove();
      }
);


<div class="myDiv" style="width:100px">this is my div</div>

<div class="yDiv" style="display:none;width:100px">this is my div</div>
```

I need to position yellow div in the middle. I think I got some of it...

[image]

Comment: CSS? I do use CSS. Can you elaborate? The yDiv will contain it's own content. Kind of like hierarchical menus. I think I'll need to calculate the height of the yDiv and append its middle to myDiv, just not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

using a little jQuery and some css this is pretty simple:

**JS**

*normally I would use toggleClass() except for the click event below...*

```
$("#myDiv").hover(
    function() { $(this).find(".yDiv").removeClass("hidden"); },
    function() { $(this).find(".yDiv").addClass("hidden");
});

$(".yDiv").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.yDiv { background: yellow; display: inline-block; position: absolute }
.yDiv.hidden { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

*this becomes much easier when the objects are nested*

```
<div id="myDiv">
    ...
    <div class="yDiv hidden">...</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/R62U3/

Comment: I agree that hiding it is probably a better choice than appending and removing it everytime.

Comment: OK, hiding if fine. Is it possible to delay the hiding for a second or so when i hover off from myDiv -- it's too jumpy otherwise. For those taking a "shortcut" to yDiv :) Also How do i position it in the middle, relative to myDiv?

Comment: check out jQuery `delay()` and css `left` and `top` and perhaps `position: relative`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure why you're adding and removing the item when you could just be hiding it.

I would `.append()` the content once, and then have the hover trigger `.hide()` and `.show()`. The overhead of removing and re-creating the nodes for each hover is - while small - unnecessary.

```
$("#myDiv").append($('<div class="yDiv">');

$("#myDiv").hover(
    function() { $(".yDiv").show() },
    function() { $(".yDiv").hide() }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a new class to both the mydiv and to the yellow div (objects can have as many classes as you want) then apply the hover to that class since right now the yellow div will disappear when you leave mydiv.  Then just add a click handler to the yDiv class to make it disappear.

```
$('.myDiv').addClass('tooltip');
$(".tooltip").hover(
    function () {
        $('.myDiv').append($("<div class='yDiv tooltip' onclick='function(){$('.myDiv').find('.yDiv').remove();}()'> ... </div>"));
    }, 
    function () {
        $('.myDiv').find('.yDiv').remove();
    }
 );
```

Comment: blur has to do with the cursor focus

Comment: use css properties left, and top with position:relative and a z-index of greater than that of mydiv